# Updating two fields at once with choices in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have `x` and `y` in my model as `DecimalField`.

Something like this:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
  x = models.DecimalField()
  y = models.DecimalField()
```

I want user to select these `x` and `y` from a list of dictionaries I have. It has to be selected together.

As an example:

```py
[
  {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2,
  },
  {
    "x": 3,
    "y": 4,
  },
]
```

We have two dictionaries in the example list so user should see two choices in a dropdown.

- Choice one with x: 1 and y: 2
- Choice two with x: 3 and y: 4

Do I need to customize some widget or field for that? If I need how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way will be something like this in which you create choices with the value that will be saved in the database something like this **(1,2)** first represent x and second represent y and split it using split function then convert to decimal type and create MyModel instance with those values.

**The second value in the below tuple is the value that will be shown in the HTML option**

**Model and Form**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    x = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=3)
    y = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{},{}'.format(self.x, self.y)


class StackForm(forms.Form):
    MyChoices = (
        ('1,2', 'x = 1 , y = 2'),
        ('3,4', 'x = 3 , y = 4'),
    )
    ChoiceOne = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MyChoices)
```

**View**

```
def home(request):
    value = MyModel.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StackForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data['ChoiceOne']
            new_data = data.split(',')
            x = float(new_data[0])
            y = float(new_data[1])
            MyModel.objects.create(x=x, y=y)
            return HttpResponse('Thanks')
    else:
        form = StackForm()
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'value': value,
        }
    return render(request, 'stack.html', context)
```